# Movie transferred via LAN shows "artefacts" when playing back

Tags: hard-drive, wireless-networking, ssd, video, video-playback

i have an SDD kingtson external drive plugged via usb in to a TPLINK EX510_4E99 router. It happens at times that when i transfer movie files (mkv predominantly), from my macbook to such drive, the movie will have some issues when playing (by any player), showing some "artefacts". If i transfer the file again it will still have similar issue, not at the exact minute but at different time of the playback. If i play the same video locally (the original file in the macbook, not the copied one), it will play fine. This issue doesnt't happen with every single movie file. It just happens randomly. Some files will play just fine. I have just tried to compress one of those files that gave me issues, then transfer it, uncompress it in the ssd and this seems to solve the issue. No artefacts. This issue i not only have when transferring and playing from the SSD, i also had the same issue when using a WDMYCLOUD drive. So it doesn't seem to be an issue of drives but of the way the file is transferred from macbook via LAN.

Any idea what causes this issue and how i can solve it? thanks!

Comment: Perhaps your SSD is faulty.

Comment: Its not clear how you are using this - I wonder if the SSD speed is a bottleneck (if you are playing off directly off the SSD).  If you suspect file corruption using something to checksum the original and copy of the file (eg sha256)

Comment: the original file, stored on the macbook HD, is not corrupted bcs it plays well on the macbook. the destination SSD has no issues either bcs it's brand new but also bcs the same type of issues was happening on another drive on the lan (WD MY CLIOUD HOME). it seems that the issues is while the file is transferring